# Firefox: "Customize" and "Toolbar layout" greyed out, can not customize toolbars

Tags: firefox, toolbar

I want to remove the Search and Home widgets.

PROBLEM: `Customize...` and `Toolbar Layout...` buttons are disabled:

[image]

[image]

How to enabled them?

*Using Firefox 16.0.2 on Windows 7. It works fine on Firefox 18.0 on Ubuntu Linux.*

Comment: For testing purposes can you [create a](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows) [new FF profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) and see if the options are enabled there?